# Error while using spark submit option --files and reading using SparkFiles class

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to pass the file using spark submit command and then read it across nodes .
The Spark code is :

```
 SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName(jobName);
           JavaSparkContext sparkcontext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
          // System.out.println("The sqlfile recieved is ::"+sqlScript);
           JavaRDD<String> fil = sparkcontext.textFile(SparkFiles.get(sqlScript));
            //Lines for debug 
           String sparkFile=SparkFiles.get(sqlScript);
             System.out.println("The path of sqlfile recieved from SparkFiles is ::"+sparkFile);
             System.out.println("The root dir SparkFiles is ::"+SparkFiles.getRootDirectory());     

             List<String> strlst = fil.collect();  
             for(String str:strlst){
                 System.out.println("The string is :::");
                 System.out.println(str);
             }
```

The Spark submit command is :

```
spark-submit --class com.load.Test --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --queue queueName --executor-memory 8G --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=2048 --conf spark.network.timeout=5000s --files /path/of/file.hql /path/of/jar/Load-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar LoadJob file.hql
```

Although SparkFiles shows the path but it is unable to read it (path in logs changed due to confidentiality issues) :

```
>      Log Contents:
>      The sqlfile recieved is ::file.hql
>      The path of sqlfile recieved from SparkFiles is ::/tmp/hadoop-mapr/nm-local-dir/appcache/application_1495017060619XXX/file.hql
>      The root dir SparkFiles is ::/tmp/hadoop-mapr/nm-local-dir/usercache/application_1495017060619_294966/spark-cd981514-4f
>      End of LogType:stdout
>        
>             org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist:
> maprfs:/tmp/hadoop-mapr/nm-local-dir/spark-cd981514-4f42-490a-aacd-3c4a9a417319/userFiles-7297d880-99a5-4a6e-8464-9c220bba77c3/file.hql
>              at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:289)
>              at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)
>              at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:317)
>              at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:199)
>              at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
```

Comment: Can you try to add files using sc.addFile("pathToYourHqlOnLocal") and then read the file using new Path(SparkFiles.get("yourHqlNamel")) ??